# MediaElement.js - How to Setup Flash Fallback for Audio?

Tags: jquery, audio, internet-explorer-8, mediaelement.js

My goal is to play audio in ie8 with MediaElement.js. The MediaElement.js Flash fallback should be used.

I'm using code similar to to what's shown below. It works in Chrome and ie9, but not in ie8. A black bar appears where the audio controls should be, but no controls are visible.

I'm not if some of the elements in the below code are correct. For example, I'm not sure if I should place the object tab inside the audio tag.

How can I get the flash fallback working?

```
These three lines are inside the head tag:
<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/mediaelementplayer.css">


<audio id="player1" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls" src="absolute path/to/song.mp3">

    <source src="path/to/song.ogg"></source>

    <object width="400" height="30" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="absolute path/to/flashmediaelement.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="absolute path/to/flashmediaelement.swf" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=absolute path/to/song.mp3" />
    </object>

</audio>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('audio').mediaelementplayer();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but I thought I'd contribute anyway as I have just encountered a similar problem and others may find this answer helpful.

Your code looks a bit bloated to me a simpler solution is thus:

```
<audio controls="control" preload="none">
    <source id="mp3_src" src="music.mp3" type="audio/mp3">      
    <source id="ogg_src" src="music.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Make sure the mp3 file is listed before the ogg file otherwise you will just get a download file box when the flash fallback is meant to kick in. - in IE9 anyway.